# Flask GET - Retrieve an undetermined number of parameters in the URL

Tags: python, flask, get, parameter-passing, url-parameters

**WHAT:** I have a Flask server and I would like to build a route and pass it an undetermined number of parameters via a GET method.

**WHY:** I would like to give the user the ability to pick several dates from a date picker, and give this list to the server which would make an SQL request to my database to retrieve data corresponding to those dates selected by the user. There would be hundreds of files and I would also limit the number of requests/responses made for performance as much as possible.

I have little experience with Flask but enough to handle routes like:

`@app.route('/photos/year=<int:year>&month=<string:month>', methods=['GET'])`

or even :

`@app.route('/photos/<year>.<month>', methods=['GET'])`

I have 3 cases :

1. The user has the ability to choose an **interval of dates**, in which case I would use a route like **'/photos/< dateFrom> _ to _< dateTo>'** (without spaces) ;
2. or a **single date**, in which case I would use a route like **'/photos/< date >'**
3. or **multiple dates** non-necessarily contiguous, and I don't know how to handle it, but what I would do would look like something like this : **'/photos/< date1>.< date2>?.< date3>?...'**
   (**'?':** representing an optional parameter ; **'...':** representing an undetermined number of parameters, just like in programming language (actually this would be enough : **'/photos/< date>...'** if a syntax like **'...'** exists).

I've been looking for answers but couldn't find something. The only thing that may be interesting is passing a JSON object, but yet I don't know how to deal with this, I'm going to look to it until I get an answer. I will also have a look to Flask-RESTful extension in case it helps.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a need for separate routes for three use cases. You might want to have a single GET route and receive dates as url params.

In this case your flask route will become:

```
@app.route('/photos', methods=['GET'])
```

you can now pass any key value pair in url as

```
/photos?date1=1&date2=2
```

you can access these params using

```
from flask import request
date1 = request.args.get('date1')
date2 = request.args.get('date2')
```

If you want a list of date just send them using same key in the URL and use

```
request.args.getlist(<paramname>)
```

However since in your case the keys that will come as parameters may vary from request to request, be careful to check if the key you are trying to use exist in the request that came. I recommend you to go through [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.args) of request object for more details.

However as a general practice if your parameters are more complex you can consider using JSON objects as payload instead of URL params.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @penguin2048, it helps me a lot.

Would you know a solution to send multiple files via a Flask server? I only know about the "send_file" method which can return a single file, and the zip file method as well, but what I want to do is to display several photos to the user in a specific template that is written in my Ionic application. In this case, I might have to specify a request for each photo...

Otherwise I can use render_template method to display my photos (would this work?), but I won't be able to use the elements I have in my Ionic app, which are required.

Comment: Sending photos to render through flask server is not the way to go. You usually want to return the URL's of image (stored on cloud) and load them directly on client side.